# Game Center in iOs - specifying a configuration for your match

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

Going through the Game Center / GameKit docs, I could not find any information on specifying game configuration variables for a match.

Let's say that you want to specify certain features a match should have to qualify for match making (e.g. you want to exclude certain weapons from the game, want to specify a length for the match etc.). Can that be done at all (if not: why?!?)? The only thing I seem to be able to find is the possibility to match certain player classes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On second thought: playerGoups in GKMatchRequest might be the way to go.

```
   "If your application sets the playerGroup property, then only players whose 
requests share the same playerGroup value are automatched by Game Center. 
You can use any values you want for player groups. For example, 
you could define different playerGroup values to implement any of the 
following filters"
```

As playerGroups is an NSInteger, I should be able to use that to do what I want.